# Traefik Proxy: Forward Auth. Totally lost with the address.how does it work?

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to use forward auth in Traefik. But it shows the error `proxy-auh-MYWEB@File does not exist`.

In the static file I consider

```
[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.proxy-auth-MYWEB.forwardAuth]      
    address = "http://192.168.<first>.<IP>:8888/proxy_auth/"
```

my dynamic file reads

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.newpath]
    entryPoints = ["https"]
    rule = "Host(`myweb.localhost.de`) && PathPrefix(`/newpath`)"
    middlewares = ["proxy-auth-MYWEB"]
    service = "newpath"
    [http.routers.newpath.tls]

[http.services]
  [[http.services.newpath.loadBalancer.servers]]
    url = "http://192.168.<another>.<IP>:6172"
```

I never included `192.168.<first>.<IP>:8888/proxy_auth` path in my website, so is it automatically created? When I curl `192.168.<first>.<IP>:8888` all is ok but when I curl `192.168.<first>.<IP>:8888/proxy_auth`  I get

```
*   Trying 192.168.<first>.<IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.<first>.<IP> (192.168.<first>.<IP>) port 8888 (#0)
> GET /proxy_auth/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.<first>.<IP>:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2023 09:07:14 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Vary: Cookie
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<
```

It connects to Apache Server but `/prox_auth` is forbidden... Why? Does it make sense? Thanks